# Grouping in relational algebra with more than one grouping attribute

Tags: relational-theory, group-by

So I am having a bit of trouble understanding the Grouping operator, Ɣ.
If had a the relation Sales(employeeId, date, salePrice) and I wanted to list the largest salePrice for each employee per day, how would I group both by employeeId and date?

For example would it be
Ɣ<sub>employeeId,date,MAX(salePrice)->largestSale</sub>(Sales)
or
Ɣ<sub>employeeId,date; MAX(salePrice)->largestSale</sub>(Sales)
or something along those lines?

Comment: What is the definition of that operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual notation is to write separately the grouping attributes from the aggregation functions, writing the attributes on the left of the γ symbol and the aggregation functions on the right, so your query should be something like this:

<sub>employeeId, date</sub> γ <sub>MAX(salePrice)→ largetSale</sub>(Sales)

This means:

1. make a group for each different combination of employeeId and date in the Sales relation, and
2. for each group produce a tuple with employeeId, date, maximum sale price of the group.